# Internet Explorer prevents domain user authentication in LightSwitch app

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, windows-authentication, visual-studio-lightswitch

In the LightSwitch *Access Control* tab I have **Use Windows authentication** and **Allow any authenticated Windows user** selected.  Authentication works fine in Firefox/Chrome but fails in Internet Explorer.  I suspect it's because Internet Explorer prepends the username with DOMAIN.  If I do the same thing in Firefox/Chrome, it won't authenticate.  Is there some way to enable DOMAIN\username instead of simply username?  Maybe in the web.config?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled **Enable Kernel-mode authentication** under *IIS Manager » Server » Sites » Default Web Site » MyWebsite » Authentication » Windows Authentication » Advanced*, and now IE logs into my LightSwitch app automatically.  I suspect this changes the preferred authentication order from (1. Negotiable 2. NTLM) to (1. NTLM).